# Exclude asset_version for image

Tags: symfony, assetic

How to exclude apply [asset_version](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-version) for images when we use assetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two options:

1. Don't use `asset` helper, which won't make full URL and won't add undesired `asset_version`.
2. Override helper method `getUrl()` in service named `templating.helper.assets` which is instance of `Symfony\Component\Templating\Helper\CoreAssetsHelper` by creating a new service extending it (for example) where you write your own logic for such rules.

If you do it second way then please share the code, in case somebody else will want to implement it later.